Wake the computer to run a certain task in C#
I want to check this box programatically:

My current code:
TaskService tService = new TaskService();
TaskDefinition tDefinition = tService.NewTask();
tDefinition.Principal.DisplayName = tskName;
tDefinition.RegistrationInfo.Description = tskDesc;
DailyTrigger dtrigger = new DailyTrigger();
dtrigger.StartBoundary = start;
dtrigger.DaysInterval = ((short)repeat);
dtrigger.EndBoundary = end;
dtrigger.Enabled = true;
tDefinition.Triggers.Add(dtrigger);
tDefinition.RegistrationInfo.Author = PriUtilizador;
tDefinition.RegistrationInfo.Description = tskDesc;
tDefinition.RegistrationInfo.Date = DateTime.Now;


"I couldn't find anything about this in Task Squeduler documentation." - I'd be horrified if you did. That's a really unlucky name clash ...

You can set this via TaskSettings.WakeToRun:
TaskService tService = new TaskService();
TaskDefinition tDefinition = tService.NewTask();

// Here
tDefinition.Settings.WakeToRun = true;

tDefinition.Principal.DisplayName = tskName;
tDefinition.RegistrationInfo.Description = tskDesc;
DailyTrigger dtrigger = new DailyTrigger();
dtrigger.StartBoundary = start;
dtrigger.DaysInterval = ((short)repeat);
dtrigger.EndBoundary = end;
dtrigger.Enabled = true;
tDefinition.Triggers.Add(dtrigger);
tDefinition.RegistrationInfo.Author = PriUtilizador;
tDefinition.RegistrationInfo.Description = tskDesc;
tDefinition.RegistrationInfo.Date = DateTime.Now;

The TaskScheduler documentation has nothing to do with the Task Scheduler program available in Windows.
